# Hard time debugging AttributeError: module 'game' has no attribute 'get_player_names'

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I'm really trying hard to implement mock objects in a test-driven basic dice game. However, when I run my test (see below) it displays "AttributeError" and I'm just not seeing why?

This is my unittest (`test_game.py`) implementation:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock

import game

class GameTest(TestCase):

    def test_get_player_names(self):
        """Players can enter their names"""

        fake_input = mock.Mock(side_effect=['A', 'M', 'Z', ''])

        with mock.patch('builtins.input', fake_input):
            names = game.get_player_names()

        self.assertEqual(names, ['A', 'M', 'Z'])

    def test_get_player_names_stdout(self):
        """Check the prompts for player names"""

        with mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['A', 'B', '']) as fake:
            game.get_player_names()

        fake.assert_has_calls([
            mock.call("Player 1's name: "),
            mock.call("Player 2's name: "),
            mock.call("Player 3's name: ")
        ])
```

This is my actual code (`game.py`) in Python:

```
class Dice:

    def __init__(self, *players):
        self.players = players

    def get_players(self):
        """Return a tuple of all players"""
        return self.players

    def get_player_names():
        """Prompt for player names"""
        names = []

        while True:
            value = input("Player {}'s name: ".format(len(names) + 1))
            if not value:
                break

            names.append(value)

        return names
```

Error Display for Tests (PowerShell):

```
PS C:\Users\Seun\desktop\dice> python -m unittest

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
PS C:\Users\Seun\desktop\dice> python3 -m unittest
EE.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_player_names (test_game.GameTest)
Players can enter their names
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seun\desktop\dice\test_game.py", line 19, in test_get_player_names
    names = game.get_player_names()
AttributeError: module 'game' has no attribute 'get_player_names'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_player_names_stdout (test_game.GameTest)
Check the prompts for player names
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seun\desktop\dice\test_game.py", line 27, in test_get_player_names_stdout
    game.get_player_names()
AttributeError: module 'game' has no attribute 'get_player_names'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.009s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Comment: where is game initialized, you import game but where is the code?

Comment: Its the second code set - game.py

Answer (score 1):

By `game.get_player_names` in your test class you are pointing to the method called 'get_player_names' **within the module called 'game'**

But `game.py` exposes a `Dice` class which exposes `get_player_names`. So you have to import the module, instantiate a Dice instance, then call `get_player_names` from the instance.

```
from game import Dice
class GameTest(TestCase):
    # [ ... your code ...]
    game = Dice('player1', 'player2')
    game.get_player_names() # <== works.
```

By the way, the traceback is quite explicit: `AttributeError: module 'game' has no attribute 'get_player_names'`, **module 'game'** is the important part.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is importing a `module` named "game".
Inside this module, you have a `class` ("Dice") with the "get_player_names" `method`.

From the error message, you are trying to access if from the wrong place.
You need to first instantiate your Dice Class to access it's methods.

For example, inside your GameTest you could have:

```
def test_get_player_names(self):
    """Players can enter their names"""

    fake_input = mock.Mock(side_effect=['A', 'M', 'Z', ''])

    # Create a Dice Instance
    dice_game = game.Dice()

    with mock.patch('builtins.input', fake_input):
        names = dice_game.get_player_names()  # Reference to the Dice Instance and not the module

    self.assertEqual(names, ['A', 'M', 'Z'])
```

Comment: I tried this but its throwing a TypeError: get_player_names() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Ah, of course... I missed that, you are missing a `self` argument on that definition (and you probably want that so you can save the inputs in the instance as well).